# How can I re-sample a wave file and create a stream or byte array instead of a file?

Tags: naudio

I have seen many examples on re-sampling a file and creating a new file.

```
int outRate = 16000;
var inFile = @"test.wav"; // 8khz file
var outFile = @"test resampled.wav";
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(inFile))
{
    var outFormat = new WaveFormat(outRate, reader.WaveFormat.Channels);
    using (var resampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(reader, outFormat))
    {
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outFile, resampler);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is create a re-sampled stream or byte array.  I have tried calling WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(memoryStream, resampler) instead of CreateWaveFile, but I end up with a stream that contains the RIFF header and I'm not sure what to do at that point.

Answer (score 0):

you can just call `Read` on the resampler to read out buffers resampled bytes. I usually recommend reading about 1 second of audio at a time, and keep going until `Read` returns 0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  I'm now using the Read method as suggested, but I get a clicking sound with the re-sampled audio.  In the included code below when I adjust the size of the byte[] "arr" higher than 128 then the audio gets worse.  Something in the way that I'm doing the re-sampling is causing the clicking.

```
public void AddSample(byte[] sample)
    {
        using (var sourceProvider = new RawSourceWaveStream(sample, 0, sample.Length, waveFormat))
        // Setup resampler
        using (var resampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(sourceProvider, defSampleRate))
        {
            resampler.ResamplerQuality = 60;
            var arr = new byte[128];
            while (resampler.Read(arr, 0, arr.Length) > 0)
            {
                // Send stream to the provider
                bufferedProvider.AddSamples(arr, 0, arr.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```